# AVX performance power function with int vs real exponent

Tags: c, gcc, simd, avx2, avx512

I am working on financial simulations that is running large numbers of calculations in the form (1+r)<sup>days/365</sup>.

The r values change between calculation, but the days parameter is between 25 and 35. The value of r is between -0.1 and +0.3.

I read that AVX can do R<sup>I</sup> (R double, I int) using a built in op - vector of 4.

Is there a way to write a fast power function that will take advantages of those limited input ranges and the AVX builtin to perform faster than standard power function ?

```
void power4ri(double r, int days[4], double res[4])
```

Comment: If the `r` has discrete values, you might be able to do a table lookup.

Comment: @stark unfortunately it’s not. There is a limited range, but values can be anything, as they re derived from market data, and precision is critical.

Comment: Using [`vdPow()`](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/onemkl/developer-reference-c/2023-1/v-pow.html#dropdown-1-0-11-4-2--8) from Intel's math kernel library is likely to give the best results on their CPUs.

Comment: There is nothing like that in AVX as far as I know. In AVX512F there are various operations that are useful when implementing this, but not still no direct built-in for R^I (you can scale a float by 2^I, that's as close as it gets, useful though). AVX512ER had approximate 2^R, but modern CPUs don't implement AVX512ER.

Comment: If you use the same `r` value a lot of times, you could actually calculate `pow(1+r, days/365)` for all possible values of `days` and do a table-look-up on that (using a gather instruction). Otherwise, how accurate does your implementation need to be?

Comment: @chtz: you don't even need a gather: you can use AVX-512F `vpermi2pd` to do 8 parallel lookups from a "table" of two vectors, a total of 16 possible `days` values, which is more than enough for the 25 to 35 range even if it's inclusive (11 values).  If you want to avoid 512-bit vectors, you could compare and merge-mask a 2nd `vpermi2pd ymm{k1}, ymm, ymm`, except `vpermi2pd` overwrites the indices so you'd actually just need to do it twice and then blend separately.  Or `vpermt2d` 32-bit chunks (high/low halves) and interleave to make 2 vectors of doubles.

Comment: I would use some specialized software (maybe Matlab or Maple can do) to compute minmax polynomial approximation for all your 11 possible day values. When approximating with a cubic polynomial, the polynomial needs 4 coefficients, they fit nicely in AVX vector. The complete table takes well under 1kb of memory, guaranteed to fit in L1D and stay there.
Afterwards, the problem becomes a multiplication of 4x4 matrix by a vector: the matrix is loaded from these coefficients corresponding to your 4 days, the vector is `[ 1.0, r, r^2, r^3 ]`

Comment: If the precision won’t be good enough, you could try higher degree polynomials. Probably 7, because then the coefficients need 2 AVX vectors each.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s an example. I did it in C++, but translation to C should be straightforward as there’s no classes.

The magic numbers were produced by Maple’s [minimax function](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=numapprox/minimax) when asked to compute a polynomial of degree 5.

The code requires AVX1 and FMA3 support.
On my computer, the program prints `1.46523e-08`

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <cmath>
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Compute the exact formula, for testing
double computeExact( double r, int days )
{
    return std::pow( 1.0 + r, days / 365.0 );
}

// Coefficients of a 5-degree polynomial
using Poly5 = std::array<double, 6>;

// The table uses 528 bytes of memory
// When you call computeVector() in a loop, the table will fit in L1D cache, and stay there
static const alignas( 16 ) std::array<Poly5, 11> s_coeffs =
{ {
    { 1.0000000115675275, 0.068493093552826708, -0.031907924120358028, 0.020574731950454155, -0.014565029805732139, 0.0077506459235939256 }, // 25
    { 1.0000000119543155, 0.071232817698572540, -0.033086615813706036, 0.021304445440744374, -0.015068060069200168, 0.0080141866662439231 }, // 26
    { 1.0000000123356091, 0.073972541873285284, -0.034257798079834182, 0.022027170104222119, -0.015565222970193437, 0.0082743302576150916 }, // 27
    { 1.0000000127114449, 0.076712266076741869, -0.035421470941346561, 0.022742926629787028, -0.016056546319775237, 0.0085310961659071684 }, // 28
    { 1.0000000130818609, 0.079451990308719506, -0.036577634420786581, 0.023451735705792056, -0.016542057876765182, 0.0087845038010732119 }, // 29
    { 1.0000000134468936, 0.082191714568997124, -0.037726288540572342, 0.024153618020104202, -0.017021785352033386, 0.0090345725258759991 }, // 30
    { 1.0000000138065801, 0.084931438857353221, -0.038867433323054167, 0.024848594260147558, -0.017495756404589998, 0.0092813216448131325 }, // 31
    { 1.0000000141609568, 0.087671163173570470, -0.040001068790504639, 0.025536685112589868, -0.017963998641832953, 0.0095247704076106266 }, // 32
    { 1.0000000145100605, 0.090410887517428572, -0.041127194965104488, 0.026217911263841452, -0.018426539621881710, 0.0097649380119523175 }, // 33
    { 1.0000000148539279, 0.093150611888710518, -0.042245811868931281, 0.026892293399711153, -0.018883406852558258, 0.010001843602650994 }, // 34
    { 1.0000000151925946, 0.095890336287200382, -0.043356919524000823, 0.027559852205404914, -0.019334627789723949, 0.010235506268121408 }, // 35
} };

// Compute a single estimated value
double computeScalar( double r, int days )
{
    const Poly5& poly = s_coeffs[ days - 25 ];
    double x = std::fma( r, poly[ 5 ], poly[ 4 ] );
    x = std::fma( r, x, poly[ 3 ] );
    x = std::fma( r, x, poly[ 2 ] );
    x = std::fma( r, x, poly[ 1 ] );
    x = std::fma( r, x, poly[ 0 ] );
    return x;
}

// A structure of 2 AVX vectors
struct Double4x2 { __m256d v0, v1; };

// Transpose 2x4 matrix in memory into 4x2 matrix in 2 AVX vectors
template<int idx>
static inline Double4x2 transpose2x4( const Poly5& p0, const Poly5& p1, const Poly5& p2, const Poly5& p3 )
{
    static_assert( idx == 0 || idx == 2 || idx == 4 );

    __m256d v0 = _mm256_castpd128_pd256( _mm_load_pd( &p0[ idx ] ) );
    __m256d v1 = _mm256_castpd128_pd256( _mm_load_pd( &p1[ idx ] ) );
    v0 = _mm256_insertf128_pd( v0, _mm_load_pd( &p2[ idx ] ), 1 );
    v1 = _mm256_insertf128_pd( v1, _mm_load_pd( &p3[ idx ] ), 1 );

    Double4x2 res;
    res.v0 = _mm256_unpacklo_pd( v0, v1 );
    res.v1 = _mm256_unpackhi_pd( v0, v1 );
    return res;
}

// Compute 4 estimated values, for 4 days with the same r
__m256d computeVector( double r, const int days[ 4 ] )
{
    const Poly5& p0 = s_coeffs[ days[ 0 ] - 25 ];
    const Poly5& p1 = s_coeffs[ days[ 1 ] - 25 ];
    const Poly5& p2 = s_coeffs[ days[ 2 ] - 25 ];
    const Poly5& p3 = s_coeffs[ days[ 3 ] - 25 ];

    const __m256d rv = _mm256_set1_pd( r );

    Double4x2 tmp = transpose2x4<4>( p0, p1, p2, p3 );
    __m256d res = _mm256_fmadd_pd( rv, tmp.v1, tmp.v0 );

    tmp = transpose2x4<2>( p0, p1, p2, p3 );
    res = _mm256_fmadd_pd( res, rv, tmp.v1 );
    res = _mm256_fmadd_pd( res, rv, tmp.v0 );

    tmp = transpose2x4<0>( p0, p1, p2, p3 );
    res = _mm256_fmadd_pd( res, rv, tmp.v1 );
    res = _mm256_fmadd_pd( res, rv, tmp.v0 );

    return res;
}

int main()
{
    // A few values in the valid range [ -0.1 .. +0.3 ]
    const double testVals[ 8 ] = { -0.1, -0.001234, 0, 0.0123456, 0.123456, 0.2345678, 0.2876543, 0.3 };
    double maxAbsDiff = 0;

    for( int days = 26; days <= 33; days += 4 )
    {
        const int arr[ 4 ] = { days, days + 1, days + 2, days + 3 };

        for( double r : testVals )
        {
            double est[ 4 ];
            _mm256_storeu_pd( est, computeVector( r, arr ) );

            for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
            {
                double exact = computeExact( r, arr[ i ] );
                double absDiff = std::abs( exact - est[ i ] );
                maxAbsDiff = std::max( maxAbsDiff, absDiff );
            }
        }
    }

    printf( "Maximum error: %g\n", maxAbsDiff );
    return 0;
}
```

---

**Update:** If you want better precision, here’s a version which prints `3.5516e-12` in the same test.
Same idea but different approximation formula, it uses rational cubic polynomials.

Despite it needs to divide numbers, I still expect it to be way faster than `std::pow` from the standard library.
`std::pow` computes more complicated expressions, and contains branches.

```cpp
// Coefficients of a 3-degree rational polynomial
// The order is a bit weird: [ n0, d0, n1, d1, d2, d3, n2, n3 ]
struct alignas( 64 ) Poly3r
{
    __m128d coeffs[ 4 ];
};

Poly3r makePoly( double n0, double n1, double n2, double n3, double d0, double d1, double d2, double d3 )
{
    Poly3r res;
    res.coeffs[ 0 ] = _mm_setr_pd( n0, d0 );
    res.coeffs[ 1 ] = _mm_setr_pd( n1, d1 );
    res.coeffs[ 2 ] = _mm_setr_pd( d2, d3 );
    res.coeffs[ 3 ] = _mm_setr_pd( n2, n3 );
    return res;
}

// The table uses 704 bytes of memory
// When you call computeVector() in a loop, the table will fit in L1D cache, and stay there
static const Poly3r s_coeffs[ 11 ] =
{
    // 25
    makePoly( 0.86260067721239053, 1.2929591411964237, 0.51623981464760751, 0.043277283717482471,
        0.86260067721248429, 1.2338769031292261, 0.45924545262672759, 0.033466985113040021 ),
    // 26
    makePoly( 0.86273250503218736, 1.2943372742953400, 0.51749050652603273, 0.043495654289650580,
        0.86273250503228373, 1.2328823562306010, 0.45820740328822448, 0.033291035144204474 ),
    // 27
    makePoly( 0.86286432731136396, 1.2957158377315365, 0.51874292347687543, 0.043714733360662574,
        0.86286432731146290, 1.2318875177348881, 0.45717038393679066, 0.033115628134939798 ),
    // 28
    makePoly( 0.86299615175525590, 1.2970947737158235, 0.51999700121891771, 0.043934510893089456,
        0.86299615175535721, 1.2308923293073432, 0.45613433444790786, 0.032940754353033408 ),
    // 29
    makePoly( 0.86312796906185182, 1.2984741518875239, 0.52125281894793519, 0.044155001775348208,
        0.86312796906195556, 1.2298968613085607, 0.45509932800210304, 0.032766423875042042 ),
    // 30
    makePoly( 0.86325978243343224, 1.2998539480383671, 0.52251035085794960, 0.044376202870253178,
        0.86325978243353824, 1.2289010893257296, 0.45406534022553953, 0.032592632446088725 ),
    // 31
    makePoly( 0.86339159540813285, 1.3012341357674331, 0.52376956717415240, 0.044598109867567339,
        0.86339159540824105, 1.2279049866897757, 0.45303234326265465, 0.032419374985963682 ),
    // 32
    makePoly( 0.86352340475592185, 1.3026147391567473, 0.52503049613676784, 0.044820728914968531,
        0.86352340475603223, 1.2269085777691658, 0.45200036283621357, 0.032246654566398420 ),
    // 33
    makePoly( 0.86365521253473722, 1.3039957427000447, 0.52629312103290924, 0.045044058228134688,
        0.86365521253484954, 1.2259118469013844, 0.45096938327097814, 0.032074468126095862 ),
    // 34
    makePoly( 0.86378701941247432, 1.3053771413406681, 0.52755743679216422, 0.045268098008621778,
        0.86378701941258853, 1.2249147889804556, 0.44993939967312269, 0.031902814167461435 ),
    // 35
    makePoly( 0.86391881859638042, 1.3067589857432825, 0.52882350257512876, 0.045492860108652312,
        0.86391881859649650, 1.2239174553298090, 0.44891046570438883, 0.031731699912992838 ),
};

// Compute a single estimated value
double computeScalar( double r, int days )
{
    const Poly3r& poly = s_coeffs[ days - 25 ];
    __m128d rv = _mm_set1_pd( r );

    // The two higher coefficients are stored in transposed order
    // Saves vector registers in computeVector() function
    __m128d nv = poly.coeffs[ 3 ];
    __m128d dv = poly.coeffs[ 2 ];
    __m128d x = _mm_fmadd_pd( rv, _mm_unpackhi_pd( nv, dv ), _mm_unpacklo_pd( nv, dv ) );
    // For the lower 2 coefficients we can use memory operands
    x = _mm_fmadd_pd( rv, x, poly.coeffs[ 1 ] );
    x = _mm_fmadd_pd( rv, x, poly.coeffs[ 0 ] );

    double n = _mm_cvtsd_f64( x );
    double d = _mm_cvtsd_f64( _mm_unpackhi_pd( x, x ) );
    return n / d;
}

// A structure of 2 AVX vectors
struct Double4x2 { __m256d v0, v1; };

// Transpose 2x4 matrix in memory into 4x2 matrix in 2 AVX vectors
template<int idx>
static inline Double4x2 transpose2x4( const Poly3r& p0, const Poly3r& p1, const Poly3r& p2, const Poly3r& p3 )
{
    static_assert( idx >= 0 && idx < 4 );

    __m256d v0 = _mm256_castpd128_pd256( p0.coeffs[ idx ] );
    __m256d v1 = _mm256_castpd128_pd256( p1.coeffs[ idx ] );
    v0 = _mm256_insertf128_pd( v0, p2.coeffs[ idx ], 1 );
    v1 = _mm256_insertf128_pd( v1, p3.coeffs[ idx ], 1 );

    Double4x2 res;
    res.v0 = _mm256_unpacklo_pd( v0, v1 );
    res.v1 = _mm256_unpackhi_pd( v0, v1 );
    return res;
}

// Compute 4 estimated values, for 4 days with the same r
__m256d computeVector( double r, const int days[ 4 ] )
{
    const Poly3r& p0 = s_coeffs[ days[ 0 ] - 25 ];
    const Poly3r& p1 = s_coeffs[ days[ 1 ] - 25 ];
    const Poly3r& p2 = s_coeffs[ days[ 2 ] - 25 ];
    const Poly3r& p3 = s_coeffs[ days[ 3 ] - 25 ];

    const __m256d rv = _mm256_set1_pd( r );

    Double4x2 tmp = transpose2x4<3>( p0, p1, p2, p3 );
    __m256d n = _mm256_fmadd_pd( rv, tmp.v1, tmp.v0 );

    tmp = transpose2x4<2>( p0, p1, p2, p3 );
    __m256d d = _mm256_fmadd_pd( rv, tmp.v1, tmp.v0 );

    tmp = transpose2x4<1>( p0, p1, p2, p3 );
    n = _mm256_fmadd_pd( n, rv, tmp.v0 );
    d = _mm256_fmadd_pd( d, rv, tmp.v1 );

    tmp = transpose2x4<0>( p0, p1, p2, p3 );
    n = _mm256_fmadd_pd( n, rv, tmp.v0 );
    d = _mm256_fmadd_pd( d, rv, tmp.v1 );

    return _mm256_div_pd( n, d );
}
```